# WebClient exceptions not caught

Tags: c#, .net, exception, webclient

I'm trying to catch exceptions from

```
try
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadData(new Uri("http://someaddress.com/file.png"))
}
catch (WebException we)
{
    Log.Warning(we.Message);
}
catch (SocketException se)
{
    Log.Warning(se.Message);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.Warning(e.ToString());
}
```

DownloadData throws exception, but the exception is not caught. I'm trying to catch Exception, but it is does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exception is being thrown?

Comment: So you wrapped your code with `try`-`catch(Exception)`, didn't you? And exception is not being caught?

Comment: @Mike159 System.Net.WebException and System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

Comment: @IvanGritsenko exactly

Comment: You might need to put down more of your code.

Comment: Please provide full code and point out the line where exception is being thrown.

Comment: @IvanGritsenko look update pls

Comment: Describe in detail what happens when you run this code. If `client` is really throwing an exception, it's almost certainly being caught

Comment: Consider changing the `Log.Warning` to something like `Console.Write` or a message box so you know its not a problem with your log command.

Comment: You are not getting any error because there is a site `someaddress.com` that returns `200 (OK)` for every request

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that DownloadData *does not throw WebException*. It will always return the data from the request, even if the status code is not 200.

Compare the [documentation for `DownloadString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx) with [`DownloadData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144188(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Problem been in Exception Settings.
But this does not solve the problem that the Visual Studio write to output

> Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll

several times before throw that exception